# toString() method printing an extra 3 characters?

Tags: java, eclipse, tostring

So I'm trying to make a toString method to be able to debug my code to check if a method builds the grid properly after scanning a text file, it numbers each object and places it on a 6x6 grid. It prints out something like this:

```
0000100
1196108
0006108
224608
355508
300777
```

However when I check the grid using a println the integer at position 1,5 and 2,5 is 8, not zero... why is it adding 3 extra characters?

```
public String toString()
{
    // StringBuilder used for storing the grid as a string instead of an int
    // array
    StringBuilder display = new StringBuilder(36);
    for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++)
    {
        // Moves cursor to next line
        display.append("\n");
        // Appends each integer of the row one by one
        for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++)
        {
            display.append(boardGrid[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return display.toString();
}
```

Can't seem to spot whats wrong.

Comment: What is type is `boardGrid` and how are you popluating it?

Comment: Hazarding a guess here, but all of the  'long' ones contain the pattern 10.  You know, like the number 10.  Perhaps append something like boardGrid[row][col]  and then a comma, and see what you get.

Comment: It is a 2d array of integers, its populated through another method in the same class which takes an ArrayList of "Block" objects to determine the number of blocks, it then scans a text file to get the data of the block (if it can move vertically or not, its size, its x, y position, its length) I can post the whole method if you'd like

Comment: Oh my goodness, cant believe i didnt see that, thank you @James!

Answer (score 1):

I think in the rows with the extra characters `boardGrid[row][col]` yields a result with more than one digit (10, 11, 12, ...).